# If $R$ is noetherian then every family $\mathcal{C}$ of ideals in $R$ has a maximal element in $\mathcal{C}.$

Tags: solution-verification, ideals, axiom-of-choice, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian

Here is the question I want to answer:

If $R$ is noetherian then every family $\mathcal{C}$ of ideals in $R$ has a maximal element in $\mathcal{C}$ relative to the partial order of set inclusion.

Here is a trial for the solution:

> [image]

Is this trial correct or I need to use the axiom of choice somewhere

Comment: The proof is correct and there actually is some axiom of choice used in your argument already. More specifically, at least a weaker version called "dependent choice". Without something like that, you wouldn't be able to pick the sequence of ideals $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \dots$.

Comment: Could you please tell me the statement of the "dependent choice" and why we need it to be dependent?@PavelČoupek

Comment: You can look at the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) page of the axiom. The axiom refers to choosing a countable sequence of elements of a given set. The word "dependent" refers to the fact that the choice of the $(n+1)$-th term depends on the choice of the first $n$ terms (here: $A_{n+1}$ needs to be chosen so that it contains $A_n$).

Comment: You can, of course, also call it simply axiom of choice.The axiom of dependent choice is weaker, so all I am saying is that you don't need the full strength of the axiom of choice.

Comment: @PavelČoupek but where is the upper bound in my case and where is the chain and where is the partially ordered set? and how I got the maximal element from the upper bound?

Comment: You seem to be describing Zorn's lemma. That might be equivalent to AC but you don't have to formulate it in such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the axiom of choice exactly here:

> If every chain is finite, then there is a maximal element.

This, as explained in the comments, is a weak version of Zorn's lemma, also known as Dependent Choice. The reason being that we have a partial order where every chain is finite, and therefore every chain has an upper bound: its largest element (because it's finite, and finite linear orders have a maximum).

And indeed, if Dependent Choice fails, then there is a partial order, a tree if you want to think about it, without maximal elements, where every chain is finite. That means that a recursive process cannot "go on forever", but nevertheless, it can always go "one more step".

This is counterintuitive, since we are used to Dependent Choice so much, that we don't even notice it. The key point is that recursion is defined with a function, so it's not "there is some ideal $A_2$ extending $A_1$", but rather a function that specifies which ideal that is. If you're only using the fact that "there is some extension", then you're subtly sneaking the axiom of choice into your proof in order to turn this into an actual recursive process.

Comment: Can you give me an explicit formula for this function please?

Comment: No. Because the equivalence you're trying to prove does in fact rely on Dependent Choice.

Comment: So there is no need for an explicit formula?

Comment: There's a need if you *want* to prove it in ZF, and in some situations you can (e.g. the ring is countable, you can enumerate it, and consider the ideal generated by adding the least indexed element not already in the ideal which will still generate a proper ideal); but in the full generality of the claim there is no way of producing an explicit formula. It's not about "need", it's about "possible".